# Using dynamic colours from server for ios app theming

Tags: swift, dynamic, colors, themes, uicolor

My requirement is to change the app theme according to the theme data fetched from server. Theme data contains all required colours in hex format. I have to use these colours to theme my app.

Response contain colours like this,

```
{
"primary_color": "#fcba03",
"secondary_color": "#262216",
"tirtiary_color": "#262216"
}
```

Comment: And what's your question exactly?

Comment: @Larme My requirement is to change app theme colours using colour from api . Don't know how to achieve it

Comment: Are tou able to download the files from server? Parse it ? Create UiColo from hexstring?